# Union of non regular and regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, proof-techniques, check-my-answer

So I have a regular language L and a non-regular language L' and i want to proof wether the union of both is regular or not.

Since I found counterexamples for both cases I want to look at more distinct cases to show when the union is regular and when it isn't:

case 1: L ⊆ L'

case 2: L ⊇ L'

case 3: L ∩ L' regular

case 4: L ∩ L' not regular

case 5: L U L' = Sigma*

I am not really sure about those cases and im stuck at case 4.

Is there a better approach? How can i prove case 4? What do you think?

Comment: $L = \Sigma^{*}$ is a regular language that cracks a lot of nuts.

Comment: Yes i used this to give counterexamples for "L U L' is regular " and "L U L' is not regular" for  general L and L'.

Answer (score 1):

Cases $1$, $2$, and $5$ are trivial:

- If $L \subseteq L'$ then $L \cup L' = L'$, which is non-regular by hypothesis.
- If $L' \subseteq L$ then $L \cup L' = L$, which is regular by hypothesis.
- When $L \cup L'' = \Sigma^*$ this language is clearly regular.

If $L \cap L'$ is regular then you cannot conclude anything about $L \cup L'$, indeed:

- When $L=\emptyset$,  $L \cap L' = \emptyset$ is regular and $L \cup L' = L'$  is not regular.
- Let $L$ be the set of all words that start with $0$, and let $L'$ be a non-regular language such that all words in $L'$ start with $1$ (e.g., $L' = \{1^n0^n \mid n \ge 1\}$). Then $L \cap L' = \emptyset$ is regular and $L'' = L \cup L'$ is not regular. Indeed, if $L''$ were regular, the closure properties of regular languages would imply the regularity of  $L'' \setminus L =  L'' \setminus (L'' \cap L) = L'' \setminus \emptyset = L'$, which is a contradiction.

If $L \cap L'$ is not regular then you cannot conclude anything about $L \cup L'$, indeed:

- When $L=\Sigma^*$, $L \cap L' = L'$ is not regular and $L \cup L' = \Sigma^*$ is regular.
- When $L=\{0^{2n} 1^{m} \mid n,m \ge 0\}$ and $L' = \{ 0^n 1^n \mid n \ge 0 \}$, $L \cap L' = \{ 0^{2n} 1^{2n} \mid n \ge 0\}$ is not regular and $L'' = L \cup L'$ is not regular. If $L''$ were regular, then so would be $L'' \setminus L = \{0^{2n+1} 1^{2n+1} \mid n \ge 0\}$. However a simple application of the pumping lemma shows that $L'' \setminus L$ is not regular.

Answer (score 1):

Given regular $R$ and nonregular $N$ you investigate whether their union $R\cup N$ is regular or not, and you state that you are aware that the outcome depends. Now you consider special cases. Two of these cases consider the intersection $R\cap N$ of both languages.

It turns out that not this intersection, but the set difference $N \setminus R$  (everything in $N$ that is not already in $R$) determines whether the union is regular.

**Claim.** $R\cup N$ is regular iff $N \setminus R$ is regular.

This follows from the closure properties of the regular languages, as follows.

**(1)** If both $R$ and $R\cup N$ are regular, then so are their boolean combinations. Thus  $N \setminus R = (R\cup N) \setminus R$ is regular.

**(2)** Similarly, if both $R$ and $N \setminus R$ are regular, then so is
$R\cup N =  R \cup (N \setminus R)$.

Intuitively the staement of the Claim is clear. When adding $N$ to regular $R$, the part $R\cap N$ is already in $R$. It is the new part $N\setminus R$ that determines regularity.

Comment: That's a nice clean proof :)

Comment: @Steven Thanks. Not shure whether it is an answer to the question, but it seemed relevant anyhow...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very clean. I also looked at N\R but always included der intersection of both so I ended up with the 3 trivial cases from above and 4 other cases which are basically all the combinations of N\R  regular/ non regular  plus the additional requirement that N intersect R is regular\non regular which is implicit but I didn't bother with this when I wrote it down. Thank you for making it so clean! Also the explanation is nice.